# Handling SIGINT in a C program that uses syslog() on ARM causes the program execution to jump to backwards a few lines

Tags: c, linux, signals

Consider the following program. It enters a busy-wait inside a `while` loop waiting for the `SIGINT` signal handler to unset the loop's condition, thus leaving it and allowing the `main()` to `return` normally instead of just killing the process:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <syslog.h>

#define RES_ERROR                                   -1
#define RES_OK                                      1

#define ARG_MAX_SIZE                                30
#define MAX_BUFFER                                  64

static bool module_running = true;

static void SigHandlerIMU(int signal_number);
static int ProcessSignalConfig(void);

static void SigHandlerIMU(int signal_number)
{
    if(signal_number == SIGINT){

        module_running = false;
    }
    return;
}/*SigHandlerIMU*/

static int ProcessSignalConfig(void)
{
    int ret_value = RES_ERROR;
    struct sigaction signal_handler;

    syslog(LOG_USER | LOG_NOTICE, "Catching SIGINT...\n");
    signal_handler.sa_handler = SigHandlerIMU;
    if(sigaction(SIGINT, &signal_handler, NULL) == -1){
        syslog(LOG_USER | LOG_ERR, "can't catch SIGINT\n");
    }
    else{
        ret_value = RES_OK;
    }

    return ret_value;
}/*ProcessSignalConfig*/

int main(int argcount, char const *argvalue[])
{
    int main_return_val = RES_ERROR;

    struct sigaction signal_handler;

    (void)setlogmask (LOG_UPTO (LOG_DEBUG));
    openlog(NULL, LOG_PERROR | LOG_PID, LOG_USER);

    syslog(LOG_USER | LOG_NOTICE, "Starting program...\n");


    if(ProcessSignalConfig() < 0){
        syslog(LOG_USER | LOG_ERR, "Failed catching process signals\n");
        module_running = false;
    }

    syslog(LOG_USER | LOG_DEBUG, "Entering loop...\n");
    while(module_running == true){

    }

    syslog(LOG_USER | LOG_DEBUG, "Exiting...\n");

    closelog();

    return main_return_val;
} /*main*/
```

I am getting different behaviour depending on the target architecture.

Compiling with `gcc signal_test.c -o signal_test` the program inmediately `return`s with the last call to `syslog()`.

```
signal_test[4620]: Starting program...
signal_test[4620]: Catching SIGINT...
signal_test[4620]: Entering loop...
^Csignal_test[4620]: Exiting...
```

However, compiling with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc signal_test.c -o signal_test` it seems to jump back to the call to `ProcessSignalConfig()`, then resuming from there (observe the repeated traces):

```
signal_test[395]: Starting program...
signal_test[395]: Catching SIGINT...
signal_test[395]: Entering loop...
^Csignal_test[395]: Catching SIGINT...
signal_test[395]: Entering loop...
signal_test[395]: Exiting...
```

EDIT: I have been doing further tests and, if I used all printf() instead of syslog(), the program runs fine also on ARM. I will update the question title to the current situation

Comment: Calling `printf()` from within a signal handler is unsafe.  You can only safely call async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler.  See [POSIX **2.4  Signal Concepts**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04), particularly the list of async-signal-safe functions. `printf()` is not one of them.

Comment: How are you determining where the code resumes after return from the handler?

Comment: @WilliamPursell  the printed messages. The program enters the loop, and when it processes the signal I can see printfs that where already printed bfore from outside the loop.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes, I know the program there works, I couldn't port my actual program so I tried to make it a more general question about how signals and handlers work

Comment: You are right, I'll try to find a way to fit the actual code

Comment: Found out that this behaviour is architecture-dependent, updated the OP with a piece of code that behaves that way

Comment: No, a program doesn't jump back, it's nigh impossible. A program can output the same thing twice, such a thing is very probable. But going back in time is impossible.

Comment: FWIW, on my computer the program won't exit on Ctrl-C when compiled with optimisations. In order to conform to the standard, *`module_running` must be of type `volatile sig_atomic_t`*.

Comment: @n.m. that is why I am puzzled, but that is the result I am seeing for ARM, it goes back inside the main() and carries on from there

Comment: Can you print different things at the first and second time? Something like `..., "Entering loop %d\n", counter++);`?

Answer (score 0):

You're telling that your program "resumes" after the signal handler returns but actually the program never stops running because it's perfoming a "busy waiting". If you want to wait for a signal arrive you should use the function `sigsuspend` wich actually block the process until a signal it's delivered to it [see help here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigsuspend.2.html). Anyway the unexpected behaviour could be caused by the flag checked in the while loop, note that it's shared with the signal handler so the variable should be atomic and declared as follows: `static volatile sig_atomic_t module_running;`.

Comment: I meant resuming the execution of the main() after executing the SigHandler. Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the process itself that executes the code in the handler, thus leaving aside the execution of the main() until the call to the handler returns?

Answer (score 0):

Signal handlers are not magic.  They are called in user mode, so they must be called in user code.  But they can only be detected in kernel mode, so the kernel passes the signal to the process and flags somehow for the process to be running in user mode, when the signal handler is called.

This happens only when the process is executing a system call, or normally when the kernel preempts the process because it has been running too long.  As the code must be run in user mode, the designers of UNIX (and this, I'm afraid, has prevailed until now) the call of signal handlers happens just when the kernel is about to return to the user process (the mechanism consists in mangling the user stack to jump to the signal handler on return from the system call, and let the stack so mangled return to the code interrupted as if the interruption were a true hardware interrupt.  This allows everything to happen in user code and not compromise the possibility of running in kernel mode.

When the process is stopped in a system call, the mechanism is simple, as the user process is not executing user code, and the signal handler will be called in a very specific point, after syscall return (so the place actually is in the point of code just after the system call ---which returns `-1` with `errno` set to `EINTR` but you are actually capable of checking this only **after** the signal handler has already been called) but when the process is preempted, there's the problem that the process can be anywhere in its code.  The stack mangling mentioned above has to deal with this, and be prepared to recover full cpu state, (like happens with a return from a hardware interrupt) in order to be able to execute the signal handler at any point in the user code and leave things right.  There's no problem with this, as the kernel saved it when interrupted the process.  The only difference is that the full cpu state restore is postponed until the signal handler has been executed, after returning to user mode.

The code for signal handler management is normally installed by the kernel in the user mode memory map (in BSD systems, this happens at the top of the main process thread stack, before pushing the environment and the `exec(2)` args and `argv`, `argc` parameters.)  But it can be anywhere in the program virtual space.

Your case here is pure execution in user code, so until the kernel does preempt the process, it doesn't get the signal.  This can happen anywhere in the loop, when the timer interrupt stops the process and the process is rescheduled again, just before returning to user mode, the stack is mangled to force a jump to the signal handler manager, 
a switch to user mode is done, this makes program to jump to the signal handler manager, it calls your signal handler, the signal handler manager then restores the full cpu state and returns to the place where the kernel interrupted the process, as if a hardware interrupt had caused the interruption.

Comment: I must apologize because I am not sure I understood this detailed explanation. The problem I am seeing is that my main() is actually going back to a previous line before and outside the loop. I couldn't post the actual code that is behaving this way, so I opted to make a more general question about why could something like this happen with signals (there's none of that "goto" witchcraft in the code, by the way).

Comment: @JorgeJuanTorresQuiroga, there's nothing that makes the call to return to a different place than the one it was executing when the interrupt came.  Why do you suspect it is returning to a different place? Without showing the code, it is very difficult to say anything. The most probable thing is that you are assuming some event sequence that doesn't hold.  Can you, at least, mark in your source code (insert a comment at the right places) where you think the interrupt has arrived (the supposed good behaviour), and where do you think the interrupt handler is returning? (the supposed bad one)

Comment: Because of the printfs before the loop. I send Ctrl+C once my program is inside the loop, and I can see that it prints everything right after the "Catching SIGINT..." trace. The program is clearly returning to the call to ProcessSignalConfig() because if I move it to other positions withing the main(), the execution after handling the signal resumes there. I will update the question to clarify this and to add that, if I take the code inside ProcessSignalConfig() and put it inside main() directly, I get a segfault as asoon as I press Ctrl+C

Comment: Well, `printf()` belongs to package `stdio` and does buffering.  It doesn't call the `write(2)` system call immediately, so it is possible that you see the call well before the output of your standard output.  BTW the signal handler does another `printf()` call (i assume) to print the `Catching SIGINT...` thing.  Never assume that the scheduling matches the output when asynchronous events are intervening.  If you want to ensure each `printf()` does a `write()` call just after it, call `fflush(stdout);` just after `printf()` call.  On every call, or use `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` to deactivate it.

Comment: @LuisColorado buffering issue is the most likely explanation. OTOH all the talk about kernel mode and stuff doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. Semantics of POSIX signals is not defined in such terms. IIRC POSIX doesn't even use the term "kernel" (but don't quote me on that).

Comment: @n.m. I have updated the OP and the title, I have isolated the problem to ARM architecture and using syslog() instead of printf()